# Matplotlib: transformation of variables for narrow orbit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have an annoyingly narrow orbit in phase space that looks like this:
[image]

What kind of transformation of the variables can I do to get a nice circular orbit in this case?
My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x,y = np.loadtxt("data.txt").T
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The data can be found here - [link](http://www.beetxt.com/Ypj/)

Comment: Is this related to the data or the plot? Do you want to change the data? What would be the difference to just plotting a circle and ignoring the data that you anyways don't like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after. What you can do is shift one of the two coordinates by the quarter of a circle and normalize to the other coordinate.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x,y = np.loadtxt("data/orbit.txt").T
y = np.roll(y, len(y)//4)
y = (y-y.mean())*((x.max()-x.min())/(y.max()-y.min()))   +y.mean()

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.plot(x,y)

t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, len(x))
ax2.plot(t,x-x.mean())
ax2.plot(t,y-y.mean())


plt.show()
```

[image]